# Is it possible to share setup/cleanup block between specs in spock using a mixin?

Tags: groovy, spock

So I could have a mixin which introduces some functionality to a test which is then cleaned up afterwards.

```
class TestMixin {
    // I want this to run after the tests.
    def cleanup() {...}

    // needs to be cleaned up after
    def someHelper() {...}
}

@Mixin(TestMixin)
class TestSpec extends Specification {
    void 'testing something'() {
        // ....
        someHelper()
        // ....
    }
}
```

At the moment cleanup() is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spock only supports "physical" setup/cleanup methods, not methods mixed in via `@Mixin`. Future versions are going to support Groovy 2.3 traits.